# Find the user who started a docker container

Tags: logging, docker

We've got many users who belong to the docker group. So any of these users can start a docker container. `docker ps` will show me all the running containers, but it doesn't show me which user started the container. The dockerd log also doesn't appear to indicate which user call `docker run`. Is there any way to find out what user started a given container?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
docker inspect $(docker ps -aq) --format '{{.Config.User}} {{.Name}}'
```

My setup:

Host: Ubuntu 16.04

Docker version: 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72

Comment: This will return the container user if it's explicitly set as part of the command line config when you ran the container (docker run --user ....), but not the user who ran the process.

Comment: @aleatha Thanks, this is still a useful answer in conjunction with your comment.

Comment: for an explanation on why you can not see which user started the container see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68505078/52074